# XOR of all elements of a list in python

Tags: python

I have this

```
A1= [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want XOR of this list

```
X=[0]
```

How to perform XOR operation for the elements of this list without using numpy operation.

Comment: Other than with `reduce()`?

Comment: I suggest using `reduce()`.

Comment: other than with reduce() is the requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda x:operator.xor(*x),zip(itertools.cycle(x),A1)))
```

good luck with the upcoming test ... the code is pretty self explanitory so just make sure you study

or perhaps you mean

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x^y,X+A1)
```

Comment: Wouldnt `reduce(operator.xor, t, 0)` work just fine?

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
print(int(sum(A1) == 1))
```

will give the xor or the list